# Bootstrap Tab formatting recommended CDN

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have an issue with the bootstrap.min.css and tabs. When I use:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

The format of the page is how I want it however when I switch tabs the contents of the other tabs are not displayed (when I switch back to the first it is displayed):

[image]

Select "Menu 1":

[image]

When I use:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
```

The formatting is not good:

[image]

However the contents of the other tabs are displayed:

[image]

Is there a bootstrap CSS CDN that does both the good formatting and the tabs please?

This is the full html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Camp</title>
        <meta http-equiv=Content-Type content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

        <meta name="description" content="A Scout award tracking application">
        <meta name="author" content="Glyndwr (Wirrin) Bartlett">

        <!-- JQuery -->
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

        <!-- Validate -->
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.17.0/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.17.0/additional-methods.min.js"></script>

        <!-- Bootstrap -->
        <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

        <!-- Bootstrap Date Picker-->
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.20.1/moment.min.js"></script>    
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.8.0/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>    

        <!-- Le styles -->
        <!-- Bootstrap -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" />

            <style type="text/css">

              body {
                padding-top: 40px;
                padding-bottom: 40px;
                background-color: #f5f5f5;
              }

              .form-signin {
                max-width: 300px;
                padding: 19px 29px 29px;
                margin: 0 auto 20px;
                background-color: #fff;
                border: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
                -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
                   -moz-border-radius: 5px;
                        border-radius: 5px;
                -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.05);
                   -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.05);
                        box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.05);
              }
              .form-signin .form-signin-heading,
              .form-signin .checkbox {
                margin-bottom: 10px;
                text-align: center;
              }

              .myheader {
                display:flex;
                text-align: center;
              }
              .myimg {
                width: 130px;
                height: auto;
              }
              .pull-right {
                text-align: right;
              }

              /* Tooltip container */

            /* Tooltip text */
            .tooltiptext {
                visibility: hidden;
                width: 120px;
                background-color: #555;
                color: #fff;
                text-align: center;
                padding: 5px 0;
                border-radius: 6px;

                /* Position the tooltip text */
                position: absolute;
                z-index: 1;
                bottom: 125%;
                left: 50%;
                margin-left: -60px;

                /* Fade in tooltip */
                opacity: 0;
                transition: opacity 1s;
            }

            .error {
              color: red;
            }

            .req {
              color: red;
            }

            </style>
        <!-- HTML5 shim, for IE6-8 support of HTML5 elements -->
        <!--[if lt IE 9]>
          <script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
        <![endif]-->
        <!-- Fav and touch icons -->

    </head>

<body>
    <div id="campDisplay"  class="container-fluid" style="background-repeat: repeat; background-image: url('images/body-bg.jpg');"> 

        <div id="includedContent"></div>

        <form data-toggle="validator" role="form" id="showCampForm">
              <div class="container-fluid shadow">
                  <div class="jumbotron col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">

                      <h3>Camp</h3>

                      <div class="container-fluid">
                          <!-- Nav tabs -->
                          <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
                            <li class="nav-item">
                              <a class="nav-link active" data-toggle="tab" href="#home">Home</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-item">
                              <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#menu1">Menu 1</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-item">
                              <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#menu2">Menu 2</a>
                            </li>
                          </ul>

                          <!-- Tab panes -->
                          <div class="tab-content col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                            <div id="home" class="container tab-pane active col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12"><br>

                                <div class="row col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                                    <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-8">

                                        <div class="row col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">

                                            <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
                                                <div class="form-group">
                                                    <label class="control-label control-label-left col-lg-5 col-md-5 col-sm-5 col-xs-5" for="startDate">Start Date<span class="req"> *</span></label>
                                                    <div class="input-group date" id="datepicker1">
                                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="startDate" name="startDate" placeholder="Start Date">
                                                        <span class="input-group-addon">
                                                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                                                        </span>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>

                                            <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
                                                <div class="form-group">
                                                    <label class="control-label control-label-left col-lg-5 col-md-5 col-sm-5 col-xs-5" for="startDate">End Date<span class="req"> *</span></label>
                                                    <div class='input-group date' id='datepicker2'>
                                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="endDate" name="endDate" placeholder="End Date">
                                                        <span class="input-group-addon">
                                                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                                                        </span>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>

                                        </div>

                                        <div class="row col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                                            <label class="control-label control-label-left col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4" for="location">Location of Camp:<span class="req"> *</span></label>
                                            <input class="row col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-8" type="text" id="location" name="location" placeholder="Location of Camp">
                                        </div>

                                        <div class="row col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                                            <label class="control-label control-label-left col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4" for="details">Details of Camp:<span class="req"> *</span></label>
                                            <input class="row col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-8" type="text" id="details" name="details" placeholder="Details of Camp">
                                        </div>

                                        <div class="row col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                                            <label class="control-label control-label-left col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4" for="nights">Nights in Camp:<span class="req"> *</span></label>
                                            <input class="row col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-8" type="text" id="nights" name="nights" placeholder="Nights in Camp">
                                        </div>

                                        <div class="row col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                                            <label class="control-label control-label-left col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4" for="building">Nights in a building:<span class="req"> *</span></label>
                                            <input class="row col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-8" type="text" id="building" name="building" placeholder="Nights in a building">
                                        </div>

                                        <div class="row col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                                            <label class="control-label control-label-left col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4" for="canvas">Nights under canvas:<span class="req"> *</span></label>
                                            <input class="row col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-8" type="text" id="canvas" name="canvas" placeholder="Nights under canvas">
                                        </div>

                                        <div class="row col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                                            <label class="control-label control-label-left col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4" for="actualKM">Kilometres Travelled:<span class="req"> *</span></label>
                                            <input class="row col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-8" type="text" id="actualKM" name="actualKM" placeholder="Kilometres Travelled">
                                        </div>

                                        <div class="row col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                                            <label class="control-label control-label-left col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4" for="offset">Offset:<span class="req"> *</span></label>
                                            <input class="row col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-8" type="text" id="offset" name="offset" placeholder="Offset">
                                        </div>

                                        <div class="row col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                                            <label class="control-label control-label-left col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4" for="outcome">Outcome:</label>
                                            <input class="row col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-8" type="text" id="outcome" name="outcome" placeholder="Outcome">
                                        </div>

                                        <div class="row col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                                            <button id="update" class="btn btn-large btn-primary" >Update</button>
                                            <button id="clear" class="btn btn-large btn-primary" >Clear</button>
                                            <button id="delete" class="btn btn-large btn-primary" >Delete</button>
                                        </div>

                                    </div>

                                    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
                                        <label class="control-label control-label-left col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4" for="outcome">Photograph:</label>
                                        <input class="form-control-file col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-8" type="file" id="photo" name="photo" placeholder="Photograph">
                                        <img src="..." alt="..." class="img-thumbnail">
                                    </div>

                                </div>

                            </div>
                            <div id="menu1" class="container tab-pane fade"><br>

                              <h3>Menu 1</h3>
                              <p>Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>

                            </div>
                            <div id="menu2" class="container tab-pane fade"><br>
                              <h3>Menu 2</h3>
                              <p>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam.</p>
                            </div>
                          </div>

                      </div>
                  </div>
              </div>
        </form>
    </div> <!-- /container -->

    <!-- Le javascript
    ================================================== -->
    <!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
    <script src="resources/bootstrap-3.3.7-dist/js/bootstrap-tooltip.js"></script>
    <script src="resources/bootstrap-3.3.7-dist/js/bootstrap-popover.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>

    <script src="js/camp.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: load CSS before the script. Also, use the same version of bootstrap in CSS and script reference,

Comment: Hi Shahil, tried this and the glyphicons disappeared and formatting was not good (i.e., not as good as using the original css).

Answer (score 0):

Use the below refrence

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">


<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

For form inputs use "form-group" it will spacing around the form controls.

Comment: Hi Shahil, Using "form-group" separated the glyph icons from the date input field (i.e., there was a space between the date input field and the glyph icon) and the text was placed above the date input field (I want it inline). I added each of the libraries with no change until the css. The css resulted in the glyph icons disappearing, really bad formatting of the date box when it appeared and the rest of the formatting was not good (i.e., not as good as using the original css).

Comment: You need to add a few custom CSS to suit your designs.

Answer (score 0):

This is the code I used to resolve it:

```
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Camp</title>
        <meta http-equiv=Content-Type content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

        <meta name="description" content="A Scout award tracking application">
        <meta name="author" content="Glyndwr (Wirrin) Bartlett">

        <!-- Le styles -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.4/css/tether.min.css" />

        <!-- Text Editor -->
        <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/summernote/0.8.9/summernote-bs4.css" rel="stylesheet">

        <!-- jQuery -->
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

        <!-- Validate -->
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.17.0/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.17.0/additional-methods.min.js"></script>

        <!-- Bootstrap Date Picker-->
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.20.1/moment.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.8.0/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>

        <!-- Text Editor -->
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/summernote/0.8.9/summernote-bs4.js"></script>

        <!-- Tether -->
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.4/js/tether.min.js"></script>



        <style type="text/css">

            body {
                padding-top: 40px;
                padding-bottom: 40px;
                background-color: #f5f5f5;
              }

              .form-signin {
                max-width: 300px;
                padding: 19px 29px 29px;
                margin: 0 auto 20px;
                background-color: #fff;
                border: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
                -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
                   -moz-border-radius: 5px;
                        border-radius: 5px;
                -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.05);
                   -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.05);
                        box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.05);
              }
              .form-signin .form-signin-heading,
              .form-signin .checkbox {
                margin-bottom: 10px;
                text-align: center;
              }

              .myheader {
                display:flex;
                text-align: center;
              }
              .myimg {
                width: 130px;
                height: auto;
              }
              .pull-right {
                text-align: right;
              }

              /* Tooltip container */

            /* Tooltip text */
            .tooltiptext {
                visibility: hidden;
                width: 120px;
                background-color: #555;
                color: #fff;
                text-align: center;
                padding: 5px 0;
                border-radius: 6px;

                /* Position the tooltip text */
                position: absolute;
                z-index: 1;
                bottom: 125%;
                left: 50%;
                margin-left: -60px;

                /* Fade in tooltip */
                opacity: 0;
                transition: opacity 1s;
            }

            /********************************************************************/
            /*** PANEL ***/
            .panel.with-nav-tabs .panel-heading{
                padding: 5px 5px 0 5px;
            }
            .panel.with-nav-tabs .nav-tabs{
                border-bottom: none;
            }
            .panel.with-nav-tabs .nav-justified{
                margin-bottom: -1px;
            }

            /********************************************************************/
            /*** PANEL PRIMARY ***/
            .with-nav-tabs.panel-primary .nav-tabs > li > a,
            .with-nav-tabs.panel-primary .nav-tabs > li > a:hover,
            .with-nav-tabs.panel-primary .nav-tabs > li > a:focus {
                color: #fff;
            }
            .with-nav-tabs.panel-primary .nav-tabs > .open > a,
            .with-nav-tabs.panel-primary .nav-tabs > .open > a:hover,
            .with-nav-tabs.panel-primary .nav-tabs > .open > a:focus,
            .with-nav-tabs.panel-primary .nav-tabs > li > a:hover,
            .with-nav-tabs.panel-primary .nav-tabs > li > a:focus {
                color: #fff;
                background-color: #3071a9;
                border-color: transparent;
            }
            .with-nav-tabs.panel-primary .nav-tabs > li.active > a,
            .with-nav-tabs.panel-primary .nav-tabs > li.active > a:hover,
            .with-nav-tabs.panel-primary .nav-tabs > li.active > a:focus {
                color: #428bca;
                background-color: #fff;
                border-color: #428bca;
                border-bottom-color: transparent;
            }
            .with-nav-tabs.panel-primary .nav-tabs > li.dropdown .dropdown-menu {
                background-color: #428bca;
                border-color: #3071a9;
            }
            .with-nav-tabs.panel-primary .nav-tabs > li.dropdown .dropdown-menu > li > a {
                color: #fff;   
            }
            .with-nav-tabs.panel-primary .nav-tabs > li.dropdown .dropdown-menu > li > a:hover,
            .with-nav-tabs.panel-primary .nav-tabs > li.dropdown .dropdown-menu > li > a:focus {
                background-color: #3071a9;
            }
            .with-nav-tabs.panel-primary .nav-tabs > li.dropdown .dropdown-menu > .active > a,
            .with-nav-tabs.panel-primary .nav-tabs > li.dropdown .dropdown-menu > .active > a:hover,
            .with-nav-tabs.panel-primary .nav-tabs > li.dropdown .dropdown-menu > .active > a:focus {
                background-color: #4a9fe9;
            }

            .error {
              color: red;
            }

            .req {
              color: red;
            }

            /********************************************************************/
            /*** Other formatting ***/


            /********************************************************************/
            /*** z-index to ensure date is infront of modal ***/

            .control-label {
                z-index: 900;
            }

            .datepicker {
                z-index: 999 !important; 
            }

        </style>


    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="campDisplay"  class="container-fluid" style="background-repeat: repeat; background-image: url('images/body-bg.jpg');">

            <div id="includedContent"></div>


            <form data-toggle="validator" role="form" id="showCampForm">
                <div class="page-header">
                    <h1>Camps</h1>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <div class="panel with-nav-tabs panel-primary">
                        <div class="panel-heading">
                                <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                                    <li class="active"><a href="#tab1primary" data-toggle="tab">Primary 1</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#tab2primary" data-toggle="tab">Primary 2</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#tab3primary" data-toggle="tab">Primary 3</a></li>
                                    <li class="dropdown">
                                        <a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
                                        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                                            <li><a href="#tab4primary" data-toggle="tab">Primary 4</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="#tab5primary" data-toggle="tab">Primary 5</a></li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                        </div>
                        <div class="panel-body">
                            <div class="tab-content">
                                <div class="tab-pane fade in active" id="tab1primary">
                                    <div class="row col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                                            <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-8">

                                                <div class="row col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">

                                                    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
                                                        <div class="form-group">
                                                            <label class="control-label control-label-left col-lg-5 col-md-5 col-sm-5 col-xs-5" for="startDate">Start Date<span class="req"> *</span></label>
                                                            <div class="input-group date" id="datepicker1">
                                                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="startDate" name="startDate" placeholder="Start Date">
                                                                <span class="input-group-addon">
                                                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                                                                </span>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>

                                                    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
                                                        <div class="form-group">
                                                            <label class="control-label control-label-left col-lg-5 col-md-5 col-sm-5 col-xs-5" for="startDate">End Date<span class="req"> *</span></label>
                                                            <div class='input-group date' id='datepicker2'>
                                                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="endDate" name="endDate" placeholder="End Date">
                                                                <span class="input-group-addon">
                                                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                                                                </span>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>

                                                </div>

                                                <div class="row col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                                                    <label class="control-label control-label-left col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4" for="location">Location of Camp:<span class="req"> *</span></label>
                                                    <input class="row col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-8" type="text" id="location" name="location" placeholder="Location of Camp">
                                                </div>

                                                <div class="row col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                                                    <label class="control-label control-label-left col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4" for="summernote">Details of Camp:<span class="req"> *</span></label>
                                                    <div id="summernote"></div>
                                                </div>

                                                <div class="row col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                                                    <label class="control-label control-label-left col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4" for="nights">Nights in Camp:<span class="req"> *</span></label>
                                                    <input class="row col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-8" type="text" id="nights" name="nights" placeholder="Nights in Camp">
                                                </div>

                                                <div class="row col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                                                    <label class="control-label control-label-left col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4" for="building">Nights in a building:<span class="req"> *</span></label>
                                                    <input class="row col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-8" type="text" id="building" name="building" placeholder="Nights in a building">
                                                </div>

                                                <div class="row col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                                                    <label class="control-label control-label-left col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4" for="canvas">Nights under canvas:<span class="req"> *</span></label>
                                                    <input class="row col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-8" type="text" id="canvas" name="canvas" placeholder="Nights under canvas">
                                                </div>

                                                <div class="row col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                                                    <label class="control-label control-label-left col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4" for="actualKM">Kilometres Travelled:<span class="req"> *</span></label>
                                                    <input class="row col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-8" type="text" id="actualKM" name="actualKM" placeholder="Kilometres Travelled">
                                                </div>

                                                <div class="row col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                                                    <label class="control-label control-label-left col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4" for="offset">Offset:<span class="req"> *</span></label>
                                                    <input class="row col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-8" type="text" id="offset" name="offset" placeholder="Offset">
                                                </div>

                                                <div class="row col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                                                    <label class="control-label control-label-left col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4" for="outcome">Outcome:</label>
                                                    <input class="row col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-8" type="text" id="outcome" name="outcome" placeholder="Outcome">
                                                </div>

                                                <div class="row col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                                                    <button id="update" class="btn btn-large btn-primary" >Update</button>
                                                    <button id="clear" class="btn btn-large btn-primary" >Clear</button>
                                                    <button id="delete" class="btn btn-large btn-primary" >Delete</button>
                                                </div>

                                            </div>

                                            <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
                                                <label class="control-label control-label-left col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4" for="outcome">Photograph:</label>
                                                <input class="form-control-file col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-8" type="file" id="photo" name="photo" placeholder="Photograph">
                                                <img src="..." alt="..." class="img-thumbnail">
                                            </div>

                                        </div>

                                </div>


                                <div class="tab-pane fade" id="tab2primary">
                                    <h3>Menu 1</h3>
                                    <p>Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
                                </div>

                                <div class="tab-pane fade" id="tab3primary">Primary 3</div>
                                <div class="tab-pane fade" id="tab4primary">Primary 4</div>
                                <div class="tab-pane fade" id="tab5primary">Primary 5</div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>


        <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
        <script src="resources/bootstrap-3.3.7-dist/js/bootstrap-tooltip.js"></script>
        <script src="resources/bootstrap-3.3.7-dist/js/bootstrap-popover.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>

        <script src="js/camp.js"></script>

        <script>
          $('#summernote').summernote({
            placeholder: 'Details of the Camp',
            tabsize: 2,
            height: 100
          });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```